# Anyone know how to get a tokens max wallet amount?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

So many ERC20 tokens have max wallet/ max transaction amounts. Is there anyway that anyone's aware of on how to get what this value is for ERC20 tokens, like you input the token, and it returns tha max wallet/transaction amount that token has?

Answer (score 0):

> So many ERC20 tokens have max wallet/ max transaction amounts

This is incorrect. Please name any such token.

> Is there anyway that anyone's aware of on how to get what this value is for ERC20 tokens

ERC-20 standard does not define "max transaction amount/max wallet amount" so it is not possible.

Comment: `0x39d8BCb39DE75218E3C08200D95fde3a479D7a14` has max wallet and max tx, devs do that all the time